# Is it still possible to render full-bleed previews with descriptions in Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I'm trying to get a full-bleed link preview as described in https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/article-rendering, so that my preview can display a description. I haven't been able to do so, and I haven't found any other posts that have descriptions present (besides interactive previews).

Does Google+ still support full-bleed previews with descriptions in them?